# Proxy/Gateway/Router server for specific ports only

Tags: iptables, proxy, port-forwarding, imap, pop3

Sorry, i don't know the correct term for this type of server. English is not my primary language.
This is what i want to do :

I am migrating my already running web app to Google compute engine (My current Godaddy server can't handle the load). But GCE block all traffic on outgoing ports 25, 465 and 587. My application need to connect to yahoo, outlook, comcast and many other different email services using imap or pop.

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/networking#blockedtraffic

So i was thinking to redirect all outgoing traffic on port 25 to 50025, 465 to 50465 and 587 to 50587 on my GCE Instance and then redirect these ports to a different server on Internet. Now this server again redirect these port to original port and destination.

Is that even possible ? If yes then how can i do this ?

I'm able to change these ports on my GCE instance using iptables nat OUTGOING rules and redirect them to my free server but i don't know how to redirect them to their original destination on my free server. I have full access and control of these servers.

Comment: Use a service provider that actually meets your requirements?

Comment: @mfinni. We already have invest a lot of time and money on Google cloud. It appeared to us a good idea back then. Yes, if it do not work then we are ultimately switching to amazon.